# IE trimming responseText of $.ajax()!

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Here is a piece of jQuery I've written that reads data of an image and alerts it.

```
    var jj = $.ajax({
        url: "/app/loading.gif",
        success: function (a) {
            alert(jj.responseText);
        },
    });
```

In all browsers it works correctly but in IE `.responseText` is trimmed into 9-10 character and that is because IE breaks the string representation of the response when it reaches a character that is not in ISO-8859.

Do you have any idea what work around or fixes are there for this?

NOTES

- I cannot use base64 because it increases the file size largely
- the page I'm writing this script on it, is a static HTML page, and is served by IIS-7.0 but the thing is I need to keep the maintanance change to absolute minimum. (because of distribution reasons)
- I hoped I can read the `byte[]` from the response instead of `.responseText` but couldn't find a way to do so.
- or maybe is there something like `UnicodeString` in javascript so I can map the ajax response to it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can encode the responseText before sending it to JS. What serverside language are you using?

Comment: well, this is also another point, I want to keep the server side as simple as copying files (because of maintainance)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
contentType: "image/gif; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: this gives me the same result.